# Probability and set notation.

Tags: probability

Suppose that the probability that the Dow-Jones stock index increases today is $.54$, that it increases tomorrow is $.54$, and that it increases in both days is $.28$. What is the probability that it increases today but not tomorrow?

I'm having trouble putting this in terms of set notation, can anyone help?

Edit: fixed title and sentences.

Comment: _Please_ proof-read your question carefully.  What does `it increases today but not today` mean? What does `it increases tomorrow by .54` mean?

Comment: Oh, my apologies.

Comment: No "conditional probability" here, please change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw a Venn diagram it becomes apparent that

$$\Pr(N\cap F^c) = \Pr(N) - \Pr(N\cap F) =.54-.28=.26,$$

where $N$ is today, $F$ is the future, and $^c$ their complements.

Comment: I thought it was $Pr(N\cap F^c)$.

Comment: Can you explain why it a union and not an intersection please?

Comment: You're right, sorry; it's even easier.